# Create customer with REST API - password does not work

Tags: customer, rest-api, create, password

i'm creating customers with the REST-API and trying to give each customer an initial password. 
Problem is, that when the customers try to log on to the shop with their mail-address, loggin in is rejected because of a wrong password.

This is my code for creating customers in C#:

```
customerLocal.Password = "defaultpassword123!";  
customerLocal.TaxVat = String.Empty;  
customerLocal.CustomerCategory = "3";  
request = new RestRequest("customers", Method.POST);  
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;  
request.AddBody(customerLocal);  
restClient = new RestApiClient();  
restResult = restClient.Execute(request);
```

after executing, customer is created, but the password isn't accepted when logging in.

I've also tried to encrypt the password with md5:

```
customerLocal.Password = System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile("defaultpassword123!", "MD5");
```

This isn't working too.

Comment: have you assign the roles to that user?

Comment: hi keyul,


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25055700/android-magento-customer-loginauthentication-using-using-soap-api

can you please explain the step 1 ), means can you give complete code for the step 1 in above link .

thanks in advance

Comment: Hi @Michael, how did you resolve this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I tried this already then I study about this, As according to my knowledge its unable to set password for the customer from API. Because in magento they are using a filter inside the customer create methode like this `$data = $validator->filter($data);`. So here the password which we sent is filtered. To avoid this I get the password before filter and set it after the filter as shown below. Change `REST API customer create method` in magento like this, it may solve your problem.

```
protected function _create(array $data)
    {
        $password = $data['password'];
        $validator = Mage::getResourceModel('api2/validator_eav', array('resource' => $this));
        $data = $validator->filter($data);
        $data['password'] = $password;
        if (!$validator->isValidData($data))
        {
            foreach ($validator->getErrors() as $error)
            {
                $this->_error($error, Mage_Api2_Model_Server::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
            }
            $this->_critical(self::RESOURCE_DATA_PRE_VALIDATION_ERROR);
        }

        $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
        $customer->setData($data);

        try
        {
            $customer->setPassword($data['password']);      //added
            $customer->setWebsiteId(1)->save(); 

        }
        catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e)
        {
            $this->_error($e->getMessage(), Mage_Api2_Model_Server::HTTP_INTERNAL_ERROR);
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            $this->_critical(self::RESOURCE_INTERNAL_ERROR);
        }
    }
```

Comment: hi Remees,


i saw your answer in this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25055700/android-magento-customer-loginauthentication-using-using-soap-api

can you please explain the step 1 ), means can you give complete code for the step 1 .

thanks in advance

Comment: @BabyinMagento2 Its only that much, you have to specify the email and password, after that check 
`if($result){ //user is exist}
else{//user does not exist}`

Comment: i added this code : http://pastebin.com/s8tCpi0t at http://hotwheelstoys.in/demo2/em0113-full-package/Mage.php

is the code format is right? please correct it if it is wrong.

Comment: It seems the code is correct, but i don't know that's work or not because your calling the full URL, What i done is i just place the php file some where in the server and include the file like `require_once('../magentositefoldername/app/Mage.php');`

Comment: whatever email id we are passing, we are getting "null" as a result. if we pass the real customer email id also we are getting  as a null.

Comment: Ohh, so there might some problem. But i dont know what our doing wrong :(.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25447/discussion-between-remees-m-syde-and-baby-in-magento-2).

Comment: Hi @RemeesMSyde, I managed to store the password into the table after implemented your code (create customer via REST API). Thank you very much. But if I were to goto the store and login using the same email and plain password, it failed with invalid login or password. Any ideas? Thanks again.

Comment: @d4v1dv00 , Sorry dude i don't know the reason.

Answer (score 1):

(Should be a comment to @d4v1dv00 but I don't have enough reputation for it).

Previous answer from @RemeesMSyde doesn't work (anymore) out of the box with Magento 1.9.1.
You need also to patch **Resource.php** as follow:

```
diff --git a/app/code/core/Mage/Api2/Model/Resource.php b/app/code/core/Mage/Api2/Model/Resource.php
index 5577628..ca6b3ab 100644
--- a/app/code/core/Mage/Api2/Model/Resource.php
+++ b/app/code/core/Mage/Api2/Model/Resource.php
@@ -219,10 +219,14 @@ abstract class Mage_Api2_Model_Resource
                 // The create action has the dynamic type which depends on data in the request body
                 if ($this->getRequest()->isAssocArrayInRequestBody()) {
                     $this->_errorIfMethodNotExist('_create');
+                    $password = isset($requestData['password']) ? $requestData['password'] : "";
                     $filteredData = $this->getFilter()->in($requestData);
                     if (empty($filteredData)) {
                         $this->_critical(self::RESOURCE_REQUEST_DATA_INVALID);
                     }
+                    if ($password) {
+                        $filteredData['password'] = $password;
+                    }
                     $newItemLocation = $this->_create($filteredData);
                     $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Location', $newItemLocation);
                 } else {
```

Btw, is there a way to modify this part without patching core files?

Comment: hi @sebbrochet, the solution works together with RemeesMSyde's patch. TQ

Answer (score 0):

in this xml file add password field
such as

```
    <password>password</password>
                <customer_id>customer_id</customer_id>
                <confirmation>Is Confirmed</confirmation>
```

dir : app/code/core/Mage/Customer/etc/api2.xml