# Magento 1.9 REST Customer Password Field Unable To Save

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, api, rest-api

Been using REST to create or update Customer record but the field password never able to be saved/updated regardless.

Below is the JSON output to Magento REST:

```
POST output:
{"website_id":1,"email":"00010@mycompany.com","group_id":1,"disable_auto_group_change":0,"prefix":"","firstname":"Newer10","middlename":"","lastname":"Corporation","suffix":"","taxvat":"","password":"Password123","password_confirmation":"Password123"}
```

The password at the end is MD5 hashed. I also tried plain text password and MD5 hash with salt separated by a colon.

To verify the record, I used Admin page > Manage Customers and verified record has been created.

However, when I tried to log in using the new email `00010@mycompany.com` it's unable to log in due to an invalid username or password.

Also, I checked the database table, the password field was never created.

I put a Mage::Log before and after the `$customer->save();` function and here are the latest result:

```
2015-07-17T08:53:39+00:00 DEBUG (7): array (
  'website_id' => 1,
  'group_id' => 1,
  'disable_auto_group_change' => 0,
  'prefix' => '',
  'firstname' => 'Newer10',
  'middlename' => '',
  'lastname' => 'Corporation',
  'suffix' => '',
  'email' => '00010@mycompany.com',
  'taxvat' => '',
)
2015-07-17T08:53:39+00:00 DEBUG (7): array (
  'website_id' => 1,
  'group_id' => 1,
  'disable_auto_group_change' => '0',
  'prefix' => '',
  'firstname' => 'Newer10',
  'middlename' => '',
  'lastname' => 'Corporation',
  'suffix' => '',
  'email' => '00010@mycompany.com',
  'taxvat' => '',
  'store_id' => '0',
  'entity_type_id' => '1',
  'parent_id' => 0,
  'created_at' => '2015-07-17 08:53:39',
  'updated_at' => '2015-07-17 08:53:39',
  'created_in' => 'Admin',
  'confirmation' => NULL,
  'entity_id' => '24',
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to resolve this issue by referring to the following [post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/40275/create-customer-with-rest-api-password-does-not-work).

Please take the solution from @sebbrochet

Answer (score 0):

You are allowed to edit everything which is returned by:

```
\Mage_Api2_Model_Resource::getEavAttributes

protected function _getResourceAttributes()
{
    return $this->getEavAttributes(Mage_Api2_Model_Auth_User_Admin::USER_TYPE != $this->getUserType(), true);
}
```

`$excludeSystem` is `true`

Therefore password is not one of them.

To change this, try with a [update script](http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-install-install-upgrade-data-and-data-upgrade-scripts/):

```
$this->updateAttribute('password_hash', 'is_system', 0);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Fabian Blechschmidt.

I am new to Magento, can you show me which file I should edit this code?

Thanks

Comment: updated answer.

Comment: I already did that and there is still no password been stored in customer_entity_varchar neither the customer can login.